# SQL INNER JOIN vs. WHERE ID IN(...) not the same results

Tags: sql

I was surprised by the outcome of these two queries. I was expecting same from both. I have two tables that share a common field but there is not a relationship set up. The table (`A`) has a field `EventID varchar(10)` and table (`B`) has a field `XXNumber varchar(15)`.

Values from table `B` column `XXNumber` are referenced in table `A` column `EventID`. Even though `XXNumber` can hold 15 chars, none of the 179K rows of data is longer than 10 chars.

So the requirement was:

> "To avoid Duplicate table B and table A entries, if the XXNumber is contained in a table A >“Event ID” number, then it should not be counted."

To see how many common records I have I ran this query first - call it query alpha"

```
SELECT dbo.TableB.XXNumber FROM dbo.TableB WHERE dbo.TableB.XXNumber in
  ( select distinct dbo.TableA.EventId FROM dbo.TableA )
```

The result was 5322 rows.

The following query - call it query delta which looks like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT dbo.TableB.XXNumber, dbo.TableB.EventId
FROM dbo.TableB INNER JOIN dbo.TableA ON dbo.TableB.XXNumber= dbo.TableB.EventId
```

haas returned 4308 rows.

Shouldn't the resulting number of rows be the same?

Comment: First query does `SELECT`, second does `SELECT DISTINCT`. I would assume duplicate values in TableB.XXNumber.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `WHERE ID IN ()` version will select all rows that match each *distinct* value in the list (regardless of whether you code `DISTINCT` indide the inner select or not - that's irrelevant). If a given value appears in the parent table more than once, you'll get multipke rows selected from the parent table for that single value found in the child table.

The `INNER JOIN` version will select each row from the parent table once for every successful join, so if there are 3 rows in the child table with the value, and 2 in the parent, then there will be 6 rows rows in the result for that value.

To make them "the same", add 'DISTINCT' to your main select.

To explain what you're seeing, we'd need to know more about your actual data.

Comment: After adding DISTINCT to the first query's main SELECT, it might return *fewer* rows than the second one, because the second query applies DISTINCT to a different set of rows. But that is minor and your main point still stands: the difference between the present queries may well be caused by duplicate `XXNumber` entries in `dbo.TableB`.

Comment: @AndriyM I don't think so. I believe that `dbo.TableB.EventId` is a typo and should read `dbo.TableA.EventId`. Thus select references two sides of equijoin condition, resulting in same value of `XXNumber` and `EventId` per each row.

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović: Makes sense, I didn't notice that, thanks.

Comment: Thank you all for contributing and answerig my question. I continued playing around with the Distinct and was able to get an understanding of the diferences. That was a "typo" by the way. My bad!